# how to wrap ui lib in own npm package?

Tags: npm, webpack, rollup, rollupjs, npm-publish

I'm trying to customize element-ui and wrap it in my npm package. I want to refer to component or style like `custom-lib/button` or `custom-lib/style/button.scss`.
When I add `"files": ["src/assets/*.scss"]` to the package.json and publish after that my package contains only package.json. I'm using webpack maybe rollup will be better?

[config](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-turing-xwosq?file=/package.json)

Comment: if it helps anyone. I solved the problem by using the npm pack command. this command takes everything that you specified in the "file" property and creates a tarball, ready for publishing